# SMS уведомление пользователей

Tags: c#, sms

Хотел спросить, может есть информация о каких-либо бесплатных компонентах или проектах, в которых можно отправлять sms уведомление для пользователей. Пользователей порядка 50к, но не все будут получать уведомление, где-то по 100 сообщений в день от всего проекта.

Comment: Можно использовать сервисы типа sms.ru

Comment: А почему именно бесплатный? Если вы работаете в коммерческом проекте, заставьте руководство раскошелиться. Пусть коллеги-программмисты подкормятся :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- смс-ки рассылает сервер оператора мобильной связи
- у этого сервера есть протокол обмена данными, обычно - SMPP
- доступ к серверу оператора для массовой рассылки смс/ммс можно получить у оператора, заключив соответствующий договор
- пишется обработка, или используются готовые решения (kannel) которые буду массово слать смс по заранее подготовленным базам
- смс-ки в конечном итоге таки стоят денег, немного - но стоят

в вашем случае логичнее договорится с каким-нибудь оператором рынка мобильных рассылок, чтобы работать напрямую с оператором нужны миллионные объемы

Comment: Договариваться напрямую - много бумажной волокиты, да и оценка стоимости будет происходить по цене юр.услуги, а это заметно выше, нежели для простого тарифного плана с возможностью отправки СМС у юр. и физ. лиц.

Answer (score 2):

Ничего бесплатного для работы с gsm нет, так же как и бесплатного интернета который можно было бы использовать в коммерческих целях, тоже нет.

Comment: Про бесплатные СМС речи и не шло. Я имел ввиду уже реализованные компоненты(модули, библиотеки) с открытым исходным кодом - Open Source.

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно подключить 3g модем к серверу. И через него отправлять смс. А стоимость смс, согласно тарифу.

Comment: 3G модем напрямую к серверу подключать не совсем хорошая идея, но ход мыслей мне понравился, спасибо.